# Unable to load multiple markers on react-google-maps using map function

Tags: reactjs, google-maps

I am having trouble while rendering multiple markers on the google map through the map function as the markers which I have hard coded are shown on the map while the dataArr array containing lat and lng of different places  which I am trying to pass to marker and then returning it are not shown on the map there is no error also I can't figure out why then markers are not being shown on the map for the lat and lng of different places.`

```
import { SettingsSystemDaydreamTwoTone } from "@material-ui/icons";
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import {
  withScriptjs,
  withGoogleMap,
  GoogleMap,
  Marker,
} from "react-google-maps";
let dataArr = [];
const Map = () => {
  return (
    <GoogleMap defaultZoom={8} defaultCenter={{ lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644 }}>
      <Marker position={{ lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644 }} />
      <Marker position={{ lat: -35.397, lng: 151.644 }} />
      {dataArr.map((el, i) => {
        return <Marker key={i} position={{ lat: el.lat, lng: el.lng }} />;
      })}
    </GoogleMap>
  );
};

const setData = (data) => {
  console.log(data);
  dataArr = data;
  Map();
};
let WrapperMap = withScriptjs(withGoogleMap(Map));
const MapComp = (props) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    setData(props.results);
  }, [props.results]);
  return (
    <div>
      <WrapperMap
        googleMapURL="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&libraries=geometry,drawing,places&key=AIzaSyAduxOyZEAyoz4mLWTgTobz_7lfDNoc-_I"
        loadingElement={<div style={{ height: `100%` }} />}
        containerElement={<div style={{ height: `400px` }} />}
        mapElement={<div style={{ height: `100%` }} />}
      />
    </div>
  );
};
export default MapComp;
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the `return` statement and the curled brackets before the `<Marker...>` tag as shown below

```
 <GoogleMap defaultZoom={8} defaultCenter={{ lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644 }}>
      <Marker position={{ lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644 }} />
      <Marker position={{ lat: -35.397, lng: 151.644 }} />
      {dataArr.map((el, i) => 
        <Marker key={i} position={{ lat: el.lat, lng: el.lng }} />;
      )}
    </GoogleMap>
```

Comment: Hi! nizhabib I tried the solution you gave but it gives the following error: Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression

Comment: Try removing the brackets, I think its just a small error. Your code looks fine :)

Comment: I edited the answer removing the brackets after the =>

Comment: It doesn't work it's the same as before no markers are being shown,

Comment: thats because your dataArr is probably empty.  Console log the dataArr before the .map function. Just add console.log(dataArr). It'll probably show you an empty array.
51x1u.csb.app I've tested it in a sandbox. Have a look.

Comment: Well, the code seems to work fine, try to copy the sandbox version. Is it loading the map without the marker? Or is it still throwing an error? If its an error, what is the error?